# Show the Invalidity of the sequence

Tags: first-order-logic, logical-validity

∃x (P(x) → Q(x)), ∃x P(x) ⊨ ∃x Q(x) 
I am trying to find the invalidity of the following sequents. 
**A** = Set of natural number 
**P(x)** : x is odd 
**Q(x)** : x is not divisible by 2

What i don't understand is how can this be invalid ? There will always exist an x that is not divisible by 2 . How can we make this false.  
 If i assume another model such that 
**A** = {0,1} 
**P(x)** = {0} 
**Q(x)** = {} 
 Now in this case if we assume q(x) to be an empty set it will not be in the model .. So the invalidity shows .Does that make sense?

Comment: First of all you should be more specific and improve the mathematical expressions. They are wrong (in my opinion) and only very hard to understand. What is $A$? Is $x \in A$? If you are not able to express your thoughts in mathematical formulas you should try to explain your problem in a few words :-)

Comment: In your example: why is $P(x) = \{0\}$? $0$ is even and not odd. Or do I not understand you?